# Why does AWS Cloud9 IDE give an "Unsupported SSL" error when accessing the built-in PHP server on port 8080?

Tags: php, ssl, amazon-ec2, cloud9-ide

(1) Spun up a brand new Cloud9 IDE
(2) Checked out my code, set up config.
(3) Ran index.php with the built-in runner "PHP (built-in web server)"

Runner output indicates the following:

Starting PHP built-in web server, serving https://XX.XX.XX.XX/.
PHP 5.6.32 Development Server started at Tue Jan 23 17:38:57 2018
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8080
Document root is /home/ec2-user/environment
Press Ctrl-C to quit.

However, attempting to access https://XX.XX.XX.XX:8080/ in a new tab produces the following error indication in the runner log:

Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)

In my EC2 control, I added TCP ports 8080-8082 to the inbound rules list for 0.0.0.0, /0

Oddly, this seems to be new behavior; previously I've been able to bring up the application in a web browser tab with no trouble.  Has anyone else run into and resolved this issue?

Comment: Accessing the server on regular SSL port (443) also does not produce the desired results, even with 443 added to the access list in the EC2 security configuration.

Comment: Hey, why the downvote?  This is a legitimate problem that other developers may encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the solution turned out to be super simple:  Don't use SSL in the web browser.  Accessing it at http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8080/ solved the problem.